# Accessing NSString from another .m file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to access userEMail `(NSString)` property in `Class2.m` but its returning null.

`Class1.h:`

```
@interface AuthController : UIViewController 
{

    @public  NSString *const userPassword;
    @public  NSString *const userEMail;
    @public  NSString *const userFullName;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userEMail;
```

Then in Class1.m im saving userEMail.

`Class2.m:`

```
AuthController *ac = [[AuthController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", ac.userEMail);
```

Comment: Where are you setting it? Do you call `[ac setUserEMail:@"mymail@somemail.com];`

Comment: Synthesize userEmail in first class.m file

Comment: In Class1.m im setting it. Tested its value right there with NSLog and its ok.

Comment: Please include everything. Setters, getters etc We can't help effectively if you don't share everything

Comment: About Synthesize - i did

Comment: Why do you have your `iVars` set as `const`?

Comment: Have you read this Question ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177871/how-to-pass-data-between-two-viewcontrollers-where-first-vc-having-two-tableview/19178950#19178950

Comment: Sounds more like you're after a singleton class check out my answer.

Comment: @iMove what has that question got to do with this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just put basic step here, change it as per your requirement.

You just need to write

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userEMail;
```

in your `first.h` file

write `second.h` file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gotUserEMail;
```

And  your `first.m` file

you have `gotUserEMail` string with some value..

pass it to anotherViewController such liek,

```
secondViewController *addView = [[secondViewController alloc] init];
addView.gotUserEMail = userEMail;

.
.
.
.
```

**EDITE**

Okay then you need to use  `NSUserDefault`.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setValue:userEMail forKey:@"myEmailString"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

get anywhere in your project by,

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSString  *gotEmail = [data floatForKey:@"myEmailString"];
```

Comment: I need to get userEMail value in multiple classes, so its wrong to send data to every class

Comment: Would using a singleton class not be better for what he is after.

Answer (score -2):

After reading a comment on another answer

**I need to get userEMail value in multiple classes, so its wrong to send data to every class**

It sounds more like you are after a singleton class. So try something like this

AuthObject.h

```
@interface AuthObject : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userEMail;

+ (AuthController*)authInstance;

@end
```

AuthObject.m

```
#import "AuthObject.h"

@implementation AuthObject

@synthesize userEMail = _userEMail;

static AuthObject *authObjectSharedInstance = nil;

+ (AuthObject *)authInstance 
{
    static dispatch_once_t instanceToken;
    dispatch_once(&instanceToken, ^{
        authObjectSharedInstance = [[AuthObject alloc] init];
    });
    return authObjectSharedInstance;
}

@end
```

then in another method in another class as long as you have imported `AuthObject.h` somewhere you can do

```
- (void)someMethodIMadeUpInClass1
{
    AuthObject *authObj = [AuthObject authInstance];
    [authObj setUserEMail:@"myemail@address.com"];
}
```

then in a completely different class you can do

```
- (void)someMethodIMadeUpInClass2
{
    AuthObject *authObj = [AuthObject authInstance];
    NSLog(@"my email : %@", [authObj userEMail];
}
```

In theory if you're creating a singleton class and not going through a `sharedInstance` (`authInstance` here) then that code is broken. Attempting to hide that brokenness is just going to cause pain later on. This is why I would chose a singleton class over using `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @downvoter Please give reason for downvote. I could give many examples (links, articles, etc) where a singleton would be perfect here. So why downvote?

Comment: Again this has got another downvote but no reason has been left. Please provide a reason for the downvote and I can correct where possible.